# How can i use Docker to deploy a Vagrant image?

Tags: docker, vagrant

I am using a Vagrant image (https://app.vagrantup.com/scratchpads/boxes/aegir-scratchpads2/versions/1.0.1) to deploy a virtual box machine with everything working but i have a problem... i want to use Docker instead of Vagrant for this (since i want it in the cloud).

Is there any way to use Docker to deploy this Vagrant image instead of it creating a Virtual Box machine with Vagrant (or get the vagrant complete config with everything it installs for it to run)?

Comment: Docker and Vagrant are more or less unrelated things. Vagrant == configure a VM, Docker == sandboxed process.  That said, there are other means to have things "in the cloud".  You can probably build an AMI via Vagrant, for example.

Comment: What do you mean with "AMI"? Also... is there any way to configure a Vagrant image to run locally in a sandboxed process like Docker does?

Answer (score 4):

Docker and vagrant both serve for different purposes

It is not possible to boot docker containers with vagrant image 
You need to create a docker image 
The process to create a docker image is pretty easy 
[Check out Docker docs to know how to build images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage)

Comment: Vagrant has a Docker provider, but "the Docker provider does not require a config.vm.box setting. Since the "base image" for a Docker container is pulled from the Docker Index or built from a Dockerfile, the box does not add much value, and is optional for this provider". See https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/basics.html for more details about Vagrant Docker provider.